# ExcelVBAを用いて、新聞PDFデータ内のワードを検索して、ヒットしたならば、検索ワードにヒットしたPDFデータをExcelに抽出したい

Tags: vba, pdf

Acrobat Reader Proを用いて、VBAで書いているのですが、どうもうまくいきません。
PDFをXML変換してから、Excelに抽出しようとしたんですが、XMLファイルが新聞の内容を上手く変換できていなくて、できませんでした。

大まかな方針を示していただけたら、嬉しいです。
また、コードも添付していただけたら、さらにうれしいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「どうもうまくいきません」では、何が起きていて、どこで困っているのかが判りません。
回答が欲しいのであれば、もっと具体的に状況を説明すべきです。
質問者が作られたVBAのプログラムを質問に追加すると良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

そのシステム全体を業務ツールとして全構築した経験がありますが、どこで躓いてますか。

基本的にはpdf => xml => コメントを1pdf or 1ページ分全文の文字列を配列に格納
=> 全格納したものを別のファイルに書き出して保管 => 保管ファイルの中に対して検索実行
=> 該当する行＝ファイル（orページ）番号を戻り値としてリストアップする。

方法でできますが、xmlがうまくいかないとは文字コード的な化けが発生しているのかテキストの格納順序がぐちゃぐちゃなだけなのか、内容から察することができません。

大体において、本件検索システムを組む場合、VBAで管理するのは結構重たいのでローカルPCで作動させるhtml + Javascriptに一部処理を代替させることでCPU負荷とアプリケーションの占有を回避する方針が推奨されます。半ばトラウマ追いましたが。